# Np-hardness reduction

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, np-hard, np

If I want to show that a problem is np-hard is it ok to use a existing np-hard problem multiple times? For example use Hamiltonian Cycle n times in a graph where n is the number of vertices? Or do I need to transform the graph into something that can easily be solved by an existing np-hard problem used 1 time?

Comment: @PeteKirkham: cstheory is for research level questions. This question will be closed, as it is off-topic for cstheory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show the exact oposite.

It doesn't prove anything if you prove you can solve your problem with an NP-Hard problem. [You can solve every problem in NP using SAT, by [Cook-Levin Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem)].

You need to show that if your problem is solvable in polynomial time - so is an NP-Hard problem. That what a reduction actually does.

For example: If I can show I can solve [shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), using [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) - does it make shortest path NP-Hard? Of course not! It only shows TSP is at least as hard as shortest path!

Comment: I think this answered my question. I have to transform my problem(in polynomial time) so that it can solved by a known NP-Hard problem. This also means that I should only be using the known NP-Hard problem  1 time to answer my original question.

Comment: @MadsAndersen: no. You need to **transform the NP-Hard problem to your problem** to show it is NP-Hard. or in other words: Use an algorithm for your problem to solve NP-Hard problem. If it can be done in polynomial time - your problem is NP-Hard.

Answer (score 1):

traveling from paris to london via new york doesn't prove that that path is the shortest one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mathematician, but surely if you can prove that the problem in question is at least as complex as an existing known-to-be-NP-hard problem, or multiples thereof, than that should be sufficient proof?
Common sense would suggest that if skinning a leopard is more complex than skinning 2 cats, then its more complex than skinning one cat, and so on!

Comment: This is nonesense. If I can solve shortest distance between 2 vertices using TSP, does it mean shortest path is NP-Hard?

Comment: I'll leave that leopard well alone then - as I said I'm not a mathematician. I did say that if you could prove it was 'at least as complex' not 'solvable with', are you sure you aren't misinterpreting me a little amit?

Comment: For the very least it doesn't answers the question. The question has a critical logic failure. every answer that doesn't mention it is basically wrong.

Comment: This common sense is called transitivity... Which might be true for a relation and false for the other one.

Comment: So even though my suggestion is not incorrect, it is incorrect due to a flaw in the question? I think our understandings of logic are quite different ;)

Comment: @TenementFunster: I am not the downvoter anyway, I just stated that you failed to mention the most crucial part in the correct answer for this question.